# how to convert string to integer in RDLC

Tags: c#, type-conversion, rdlc

I want to convert string number like **"000023"** to integer **000023** in RDLC report but when I am trying to convert it into integer it only **displays 23 instead of 000023**.

does anyone know how to do this ?

thanks

Comment: It is logical.Why you do not want to let is string?

Comment: @kostasch. because I want to convert this integer to culture wise format

Comment: I think you can not do that in rdlc and i think you can not do that even on crystal (i am not sure).

Comment: is there any other way I can do this ? this number will come from database

Comment: If you want the format as per culture, then why do yuo expect to be able to format it yourself at the same time? You either format it as _you_ want, and for that, yuo keep it as a string, or you use the formatting provided but the culture, and you get what you say you want (23).

Comment: I think that you can't. I am not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[*Jaq316's answer*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19559267/447156) is correct.

How could you have an [`int`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.aspx) as `000023`? You could format it as a string with leading zeros which you have already it as a string.

But if you want to display `23` as a `000023` you can use [`String.PadLeft`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92h5dc07%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) like;

```
public string Represent(string s)
{
    int i = 0;
    if (int.TryParse(s, out i))
    {
        return(i.ToString().PadLeft(6,'0'));
    }
}
```

This method seems pointless of course since you have already `000023` in your database.

Answer (score 4):

000023 is not an valid integer. When 000023 is converted to an integer, it will automatically be converted to the valid integer 23.

Answer (score 1):

Integral types and Floating point types doesn't owns any formatting.

Formatting is done only when converting them to string. so you've to format it when you display it. There is no way to store an integer as *000023*